# Is it possible to return the correct values from a list of dictionaries based on user inputted subject ID?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I apologize for any formatting issues or unclear parts, I'm VERY new to Python and programming in general. I want to make a script that pulls a list of research participant records (the code provided here is sample data) and the list contains separate dictionary-like items that have all of the screening questions (including the record id, or subject ID). I want to pull particular items (self-harm reports and suicidal thoughts questions) from this depending on what the script's user inputs as the record id

I want the script to be able to pull from a growing list of dictionaries, so it has to index So far I have tried to return a tuple based on the user input, but it returns the same values 
regardless of what I input for subj, it returns the same three values ('1', '2', '1'), the values of ONLY the first dictionary

```
 from redcap import Project, RedcapError
 URL = 'https://redcap.lib.umd.edu/api/'
 #API KEY for sample data
 API_KEY = 'B2E685118B86FA89F57C49A1C9A38BDC'
 project = Project(URL, API_KEY)
 all_data = project.export_records()
 def find(subj, data):
  index = 0
  j = 0
   for i in data:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if k == 'record_id' and v == subj:
            index = j
            j+=1
        else:
            j+=1
    return data[index]['record_id'],data[index]['selfharm_18yr'],data[index]['talksaboutkillingself_18yr']
```

AN EXAMPLE OF DATA RECORD

```
 [{'record_id': '1', 'child_gender': '', 'c_age': '', 'c_dob': '', 't_date': '', 'school_yn': '', 'school_grade': '', 'father_job': '', 'mother_work': '', 'parentgender': '', 'relation_to_child': '', 'other': '', 'no_sports': '', 'sport_a': '', 'average_time_a': '', 'average_skill_a': '', 'sport_b_yes': '', 'sport_b': '', 'average_time_b': '', 'average_skill_b': '', 'sport_c_yes': '', 'sport_c': '', 'average_time_c': '', 'average_skill_c': '', 'hobby_a_yes': '', 'hobby_a': '', 'hobby_a_time': '', 'hobby_a_skill': '', 'hobby_b_yes': '', 'hobby_b': '', 'hobby_b_time': '', 'hobby_b_skill': '', 'hobby_c_yes': '', 'hobby_c': '', 'hobby_c_time': '', 'hobby_c_skill': '', 'clubs': '', 'club1': '', 'activeclub1': '', 'clubs_2': '', 'club2': '', 'activeclub2': '', 'clubs_3': '', 'club3': '', 'activeclub3': '', 'chore_a_yes': '', 'chore_a': '', 'chore_a_skill': '', 'chore_b_yes': '', 'chore_b': '', 'chore_b_skill': '', 'chore_c_yes': '', 'chore_c': '', 'chore_c_skill': '', 'close_friends': '', 'friends': '', 'get_along_siblings': '', 'along_withkids': '', 'behave': '', 'play_work': '', 'attend_school': '', 'school_reason': '', 'performance1': '', 'performance2': '', 'performance3': '', 'performance4': '', 'othersubjects': '', 'other_subjects': '', 'performanceother': '', 'other2': '', 'other_subjects_2': '', 'performanceother_2': '', 'other3': '', 'other_subjects_3': '', 'performanceother_3': '', 'specialeducation': '', 'sp_ed': '', 'repeat_grades': '', 'repeat2': '', 'academic_problems': '', 'describe_problems': '', 'problems_date': '', 'problems_yn': '', 'end_problems': '', 'disabilities': '', 'disability2': '', 'concerns': '', 'best_things': '', 'too_young': '', 'alcohol': '', 'describe_alc18yr': '', 'argues': '', 'fails_finishing_things': '', 'enjoyment': '', 'bm': '', 'bragging': '', 'concentration': '', 'obsessions': '', 'describe_obesessions': '', 'restlessness': '', 'dependence': '', 'lonely': '', 'confusion': '', 'crying': '', 'cruelty_animals': '', 'cruelty': '', 'daydreams': '', 'selfharm_18yr': '2', 'attention': '', 'destruction': '', 'destruction2': '', 'disobedience': '', 'school_disobedience': '', 'eating_well': '', 'getting_along': '', 'guilt_misbehaving': '', 'jealousy': '', 'rule_breaking': '', 'fearful': '', 'describe_fears': '', 'fears_school': '', 'fears_thoughts': '', 'perfection': '', 'loveless': '', 'others_outtoget': '', 'worthlessness': '', 'accident_prone': '', 'fights': '', 'teasing': '', 'trouble_makers': '', 'voices': '', 'describe_voices': '', 'impulsive_acts': '', 'solitary': '', 'lying_cheating': '', 'fingernails': '', 'tense': '', 'movements': '', 'describe_movements': '', 'nightmares': '', 'likeability': '', 'constipation': '', 'fear_anxiety': '', 'dizziness': '', 'guilt': '', 'overeating': '', 'overtired': '', 'overweight': '', 'aches_pains': '', 'headaches': '', 'nausea': '', 'eye_problems': '', 'describe_eyes': '', 'skin_problems': '', 'stomach_aches': '', 'vomiting': '', 'other_conditions': '', 'describe_other': '', 'physical_violence': '', 'picks_skin': '', 'describe_skin': '', 'public': '', 'public2': '', 'school_work': '', 'coordination': '', 'older_kids': '', 'younger_kids': '', 'talking_refusal': '', 'compulsions': '', 'describe_compulsions': '', 'runs_away': '', 'screams': '', 'secretive': '', 'seeing_things': '', 'describe_seeingthings': '', 'self_conscious': '', 'sets_fires': '', 'sexual_problems': '', 'describe_sexualproblems': '', 'clowning': '', 'shy_timid': '', 'sleeps_less': '', 'sleeps_more': '', 'describe_sleeping': '', 'inattentive': '', 'speech_problems': '', 'describe_speechproblems': '', 'stares_blankly': '', 'steals_home': '', 'steals_outside': '', 'stores': '', 'describe_hoarding': '', 'strange_behavior': '', 'describe_strangebehavior': '', 'strange_ideas': '', 'describe_ideas': '', 'stubborn_sullen': '', 'mood_changes': '', 'sulking': '', 'suspicious': '', 'swearing_obscenities': '', 'talksaboutkillingself_18yr': '1', 'sleeptalking_walking': '', 'describe_sleeptalking': '', 'talks_toomuch': '', 'frequent_teasing': '', 'temper_tantrums': '', 'thinks_sex': '', 'threatens_people': '', 'thumb_sucking': '', 'smoking': '', 'sleeping_troubles': '', 'describe_sleepingtroubles': '', 'truancy': '', 'low_energy': '', 'depression': '', 'loud': '', 'uses_drugs': '', 'describe_drugusage': '', 'vandalism': '', 'wets_self': '', 'wets_bed': '', 'whining': '', 'opposite_sex': '', 'withdrawn': '', 'frequent_worries': '', 'additional_problems': '', 'problem_a': '', 'prob_a_true': '', 'problem_b_yes': '', 'problem_b': '', 'prob_b_true': '', 'problem_c_yes': '', 'problem_c': '', 'prob_c_true': ''}, {'record_id': '2', 'child_gender': '', 'c_age': '', 'c_dob': '', 't_date': '', 'school_yn': '', 'school_grade': '', 'father_job': '', 'mother_work': '', 'parentgender': '', 'relation_to_child': '', 'other': '', 'no_sports': '', 'sport_a': '', 'average_time_a': '', 'average_skill_a': '', 'sport_b_yes': '', 'sport_b': '', 'average_time_b': '', 'average_skill_b': '', 'sport_c_yes': '', 'sport_c': '', 'average_time_c': '', 'average_skill_c': '', 'hobby_a_yes': '', 'hobby_a': '', 'hobby_a_time': '', 'hobby_a_skill': '', 'hobby_b_yes': '', 'hobby_b': '', 'hobby_b_time': '', 'hobby_b_skill': '', 'hobby_c_yes': '', 'hobby_c': '', 'hobby_c_time': '', 'hobby_c_skill': '', 'clubs': '', 'club1': '', 'activeclub1': '', 'clubs_2': '', 'club2': '', 'activeclub2': '', 'clubs_3': '', 'club3': '', 'activeclub3': '', 'chore_a_yes': '', 'chore_a': '', 'chore_a_skill': '', 'chore_b_yes': '', 'chore_b': '', 'chore_b_skill': '', 'chore_c_yes': '', 'chore_c': '', 'chore_c_skill': '', 'close_friends': '', 'friends': '', 'get_along_siblings': '', 'along_withkids': '', 'behave': '', 'play_work': '', 'attend_school': '', 'school_reason': '', 'performance1': '', 'performance2': '', 'performance3': '', 'performance4': '', 'othersubjects': '', 'other_subjects': '', 'performanceother': '', 'other2': '', 'other_subjects_2': '', 'performanceother_2': '', 'other3': '', 'other_subjects_3': '', 'performanceother_3': '', 'specialeducation': '', 'sp_ed': '', 'repeat_grades': '', 'repeat2': '', 'academic_problems': '', 'describe_problems': '', 'problems_date': '', 'problems_yn': '', 'end_problems': '', 'disabilities': '', 'disability2': '', 'concerns': '', 'best_things': '', 'too_young': '', 'alcohol': '', 'describe_alc18yr': '', 'argues': '', 'fails_finishing_things': '', 'enjoyment': '', 'bm': '', 'bragging': '', 'concentration': '', 'obsessions': '', 'describe_obesessions': '', 'restlessness': '', 'dependence': '', 'lonely': '', 'confusion': '', 'crying': '', 'cruelty_animals': '', 'cruelty': '', 'daydreams': '', 'selfharm_18yr': '3', 'attention': '', 'destruction': '', 'destruction2': '', 'disobedience': '', 'school_disobedience': '', 'eating_well': '', 'getting_along': '', 'guilt_misbehaving': '', 'jealousy': '', 'rule_breaking': '', 'fearful': '', 'describe_fears': '', 'fears_school': '', 'fears_thoughts': '', 'perfection': '', 'loveless': '', 'others_outtoget': '', 'worthlessness': '', 'accident_prone': '', 'fights': '', 'teasing': '', 'trouble_makers': '', 'voices': '', 'describe_voices': '', 'impulsive_acts': '', 'solitary': '', 'lying_cheating': '', 'fingernails': '', 'tense': '', 'movements': '', 'describe_movements': '', 'nightmares': '', 'likeability': '', 'constipation': '', 'fear_anxiety': '', 'dizziness': '', 'guilt': '', 'overeating': '', 'overtired': '', 'overweight': '', 'aches_pains': '', 'headaches': '', 'nausea': '', 'eye_problems': '', 'describe_eyes': '', 'skin_problems': '', 'stomach_aches': '', 'vomiting': '', 'other_conditions': '', 'describe_other': '', 'physical_violence': '', 'picks_skin': '', 'describe_skin': '', 'public': '', 'public2': '', 'school_work': '', 'coordination': '', 'older_kids': '', 'younger_kids': '', 'talking_refusal': '', 'compulsions': '', 'describe_compulsions': '', 'runs_away': '', 'screams': '', 'secretive': '', 'seeing_things': '', 'describe_seeingthings': '', 'self_conscious': '', 'sets_fires': '', 'sexual_problems': '', 'describe_sexualproblems': '', 'clowning': '', 'shy_timid': '', 'sleeps_less': '', 'sleeps_more': '', 'describe_sleeping': '', 'inattentive': '', 'speech_problems': '', 'describe_speechproblems': '', 'stares_blankly': '', 'steals_home': '', 'steals_outside': '', 'stores': '', 'describe_hoarding': '', 'strange_behavior': '', 'describe_strangebehavior': '', 'strange_ideas': '', 'describe_ideas': '', 'stubborn_sullen': '', 'mood_changes': '', 'sulking': '', 'suspicious': '', 'swearing_obscenities': '', 'talksaboutkillingself_18yr': '2', 'sleeptalking_walking': '', 'describe_sleeptalking': '', 'talks_toomuch': '', 'frequent_teasing': '', 'temper_tantrums': '', 'thinks_sex': '', 'threatens_people': '', 'thumb_sucking': '', 'smoking': '', 'sleeping_troubles': '', 'describe_sleepingtroubles': '', 'truancy': '', 'low_energy': '', 'depression': '', 'loud': '', 'uses_drugs': '', 'describe_drugusage': '', 'vandalism': '', 'wets_self': '', 'wets_bed': '', 'whining': '', 'opposite_sex': '', 'withdrawn': '', 'frequent_worries': '', 'additional_problems': '', 'problem_a': '', 'prob_a_true': '', 'problem_b_yes': '', 'problem_b': '', 'prob_b_true': '', 'problem_c_yes': '', 'problem_c': '', 'prob_c_true': ''}]
```

I expect it to output a truple of the three keys, depending on what the record id of the corresponding dictionary is, but it instead outputs the same thing regardless of the subject ID

AN EXAMPLE OF THE OUTPUT

```
 find('1', all_data)
 ('1', '2', '1')

 find('2', all_data)
 ('1', '2', '1')
```

In the future I also want to be able to send those to an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: To clarify a point: Is this API key something that should be available to the public? Generally you want to obfuscate unique identifiers like this on a public site like SO

Comment: @G.Anderson it's an API for completely useless data I created for this purpose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case, you're doing a ton of unnecessary iteration. The beauty of python dictionaries is that they're hashed and optimized for lookup operations.

Rather than iterating through keys and values, all you need to do is supply the key as the index and return early if the record exists. (Note, I changed a few names around for clarity, and to ensure that things like `find()` don't shadow built-in methods from other classes)

```
def find_item(subj, data):
    for subdict in data:
        if subdict['record_id']== subj:
            return subdict['record_id'],subdict['selfharm_18yr'],subdict['talksaboutkillingself_18yr']
    return "No Records Found"

find_item('1',data)
('1', '2', '1')

find_item('2',data)
('2', '3', '2')

find_item('zyzzyx',data)
"No records found"
```

And, regarding your function, here's where I believe the problem lies:

```
if k == 'record_id' and v == subj:
    index = j
    j+=1
else:
    j+=1
```

In the case of the provided list of 2 records, this means you're setting `index==0` *before* you update j, so even if the record is found at `i[1]`, you still return the values from `i[0]`

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks a ton, I can finally move on lol. And, I suspected the problem was there, just didn't know how to solve it properly. I really appreciate it